extract ca chain that has multiple CA as list from vault using jq and format into single ca.crt file
I trying to generate certs uisng vault pki role. How can i create a single file called ca.crt from the wget command output.
$ wget --method=POST --header="X-Vault-Namespace: ns" --header="X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" --body-data='{"common_name": "test.example.com", "ttl": "5m"}' https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/pki/dev/issuing_ca/issue/dev -q -O - | jq '.data.ca_chain'
Response
[
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIF5jCCA86W6j2PehfjWs3\nR55ogX1Z2jk/dvIIp.......Z067gh7nrDE56fzhyA=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIF4DCCA8iNzdTHItwqVl1cTglr6bcry0vckey68u+.......4gR0CRtJ\nCaLcNKCBGi/jn6pekNVvgjBamsM=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIFMzCCAxnNDE5MTlaFwumZ8\nHL8n10r0b35LtMT........CxSXIjAZJRE8Fh9jOIm0\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
]


$ cat ca.crt

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF5jCCA86W6j2PehfjWs3
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF5jCCA86W6j2PehfjWs3
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
nMIIF4DCCA8iNzdTHItwqVl1c
.
.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Try jq -r '.data.ca_chain[]' > ca.crt

You'll need to output raw (-r) and combine the array into a single output ([]).
Don't forget an > ca.crt to actually write the output to a file.
wget ... | jq -r '.data.ca_chain[]' > ca.crt


From OP's comment, to save this in a variable before writing to a file:
result="$(wget ... | jq -r '.data.ca_chain[]' > ca.crt)"
echo -e "Final cert:\n $result"
echo "$result" > ca.crt 

Don't forget the quotes ("") around bash variables, those are very important in this case:

When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?


I don't know if i can update the question but the requirement was to store the output in a variable and then echo to ca.crt file. But when i store in a variable and echo to file, all the three CA's are flattened and coming as a single string.

You'll need to show us what you're doing. But it should be something like result="$(wget + jq)"; echo "$result"; and then write to a file: echo "$result" > ca.crt. But that has the same result of adding > ca.crt to the complete command.

$ cat ca.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----... MIIF5jCCA86W6j2PehfjWs3...-----END CERTIFICATE-----....-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----..MIIF5jCCA86W6j2PehfjWs3...-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----nMIIF4DCCA8iNzdTHItwqVl1c-----END CERTIFICATE-----```

All the CA's are flattened into a single file when use store the result in a variable.

I've added an exmale in the answer @Raghavendra
